# Нужно убрать в выдаче тэг <b> используется BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Код, приведенный ниже, парсит в .csv файл url'ы из поисковой выдачи яндекса, но парсит с тегом "b""/b" получается подобное - **doc-me.ru**
Нужно избавиться от тега "b""/b". Как, для этого, исправить код?
Кавычки раставлены специально, чтобы stackoverflow не воспринимал теги, как **жирный текст**
т.е. нужно вытащить то, что находиться в теге "жирный текст" - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правки будут в этой строке:
items = soup.find_all('a', {'class' : 'link link_outer_yes link_theme_outer path__item i-bem'})

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


def get_html(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.text


def get_data_items(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    items = soup.find_all('a', {'class' : 'link link_outer_yes link_theme_outer path__item i-bem'})
    # return [a.get('href') for a in items]
    for a in items:
        href_soup = a.get('href')
        data = {'url': a,
                'href': href_soup}
        write_data_csv(data)


def write_data_csv(data):
    with open('data.csv', 'a') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow((data['url']))


def main():
    url = 'https://yandex.ru/search/?clid=9582&text=скачать&lr=118890&p=1'
    print('Парсим следующий url:')
    print(url)
    # print(get_data_items(get_html(url)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Во время прохода по полученным объектам здесь:

```
for a in items:
```

можно добавить :

```
text = a.b.text
```

тогда в переменную text при каждом новом проходе буде записываться текст из тега b

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ.